# Android - how to unregister the registerReceiver from other class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My problem here I get leaked from registedReceiver. I searched for any instruction on how I should close the registedReceiver they instruct that you should close it to the onPause or ondestroy but I can't find anything on how I close mine.

My Code

```
public class SMSHandler{    

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    public SMSHandler(Context context, String phoneNum, String message){
        sendSMS(context,phoneNum,message);
    }

    private void sendSMS(Context context,String phoneNum, String message) {

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(
                SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        // when the sms has been sent
        context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(SENT));

        context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS note delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't unregister an anonymous object.  Try keeping a reference somewhere where you can share the receiver with other clients.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the BroadCastReceiver Anonymously, there is no specific object which has reference to these class. Use them inside another class and use here with an Object, that you can access from wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to register and unregister receiver...

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // Your onReceive code here...
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RTLog.d(TAG, "Destroy Called");
    // unregister the receiver
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Comment: where that timerBroadcastReceiver come from?
I know that in unregisterReceiver you need Broadcastreceiver as parameter, but how should I call those broadcastreceiver that I set?